# Binding FontSize in Silverlight style not changing

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

I have a set of styles that I am binding to a viewmodel. This works fine for the backgrounds and foregrounds. I am now wanting to bind the fontsize. I can get the binding to work, but when I change the value and call PropertyChanged for that property, it doesn't get the new value. Any ideas?

**sample.xaml**

```
<Style x:Key="ApplicationNameStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource NavigationForegroundColorBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding FontSize12, Source={StaticResource Sampe}}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Effect">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" Opacity="0.25" ShadowDepth="0"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

sampleviewmodel.cs

```
public Double FontSize12
{
    get
    {
         return _fontSize12;
    }
    set
    {
        _fontSize12 = value;
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("FontSize12"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce a problem.  I set up an example project using your Style, added a sample view-model object, and added a TextBlock using your style and a button that added 2 to the font size in the view-model object when I clicked it.  This behaved as expected: the font got bigger and bigger every time I clicked the button.  What values are you trying to set to the font size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to set your binding `Mode=TwoWay`. This will make any change made on your object to be reflected on the UI.

Comment: Thanks that took care of it.